# How do I automatically connect a database to an SQL Server through Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I just installed SQL Server Express 2017 on my Windows 11 laptop. I'm now trying to write a project in C# using VS 2022 and every time I try to create a new database by selecting Add -> New Item, then selecting Service-based Database and clicking the Add button, I keep getting this message:

[This is the error message I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ip0o.jpg)

I'm figuring I have to some how change the server name, remove any password to it if there is one on the SQL Server side and probably set an option in Visual Studio.

I tried going into SQL Server 2017 and change the server name, remove the password, and set it so it automatically starts.
I also went into Visual Studio 2022 and looked for options that could be changed to link up to that serve. I didn't find any.

Comment: I have a question, why are you creating database again and again?

Comment: I think that you need to have installed LocalDB as a VS component in order to create a database that way. I don't think that it will find an instance of SQL Server Express installed separately. If it can do, you would presumably have to specify the instance name in the VS options.

Comment: If you've installed SQL Express, you may consider [Downloading SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver16) and use it to create your database and create a user that your application can use.

Comment: You may also consider searching for `Entity Framework`, `Dapper`, `t-sql`. The following may be useful as well:  [Connection Strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

Comment: Check the db name using Sql Server Configuration Manager through windows, Check you have the correct authentication setup, so in MSSQL you can enable mixed mode authentication for both windows and normal sql logins(username & password).

Try to make sure you can connect through SSMS first, then you will know if its a code issue or something to do with the db.

Comment: I only want to create the database once using VS. but in the past on other computers when I did that the database would be created and the connection string would be automatically create with Server=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB and everything worked fine. Now on a new computer I'm having trouble.

Comment: If using VS 2022, you may have a look at `SQL Server Object Explorer` (In VS menu, `View` => `SQL Server Object Explorer`). Then right-click `SQL Server` and select `Add SQL Server`. If SQL Express is running on your local computer, expand `Local` and select your instance of SQL Express.